# DIV onmouseover - does not stack over on top of all others DIV?

Tags: css

I would like my  appears on top of all others  onmouseover !
But it does not !

Here is my CSS style with (display:inline-block) :

```
.changeMyTitle .two{
  display: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: justify;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 225%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: serif;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 25px 8px 10px 2px rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.8); /* WebKit */
  -moz-box-shadow: 25px 8px 10px 2px rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.8); /* Firefox */
  box-shadow: 25px 8px 10px 2px rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.8); /* Standard */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.changeMyTitle:hover .two{
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Should it be `.changeMyTitle .two:hover`? Hard to know what you're trying to do with just CSS.

Comment: Please provide enough HTML for us to recreate your issue and explain how it is going wrong

Comment: If you could build an example (http://jsfiddle.net/) it would really help to understand your problem

Comment: I just tried your idea (.two:hover) without good result ! But at least I did tried your code and I thank you for your idea ! Here is a link to see it alive = ( http://www.parisgratuit.com/xlagenda322/include/diagram-map-paris-broc.html ) - My code (html and css) works ok alone - When I add this code within my big php page, it fails to respond positively - ie the div onmouseover should appears on top over the map of Paris !